How to produce an intermittent square wave (produced by XY-LPWM module)?
I'm a novice DIY guy trying to make a PEMF device (Pulsed electromagnetic field therapy). According to a paper I'm reading, I need to produce two PWM waves like this (B0 and B1 in the abstract picture below).

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 to talk to two XY-LPWM modules through UART (like here).
Supposedly, the B0 wave has the frequency of 10Hz to 50Hz. At 50, a cycle is 0.02s. The B1 (lower graph) wave is only turned on at the second half of the cycle and it needs to be off at the first half, like in the figure. I can produce the B0 just fine. But B1 wave, I cannot.
The problem is, the XY-LPWM module cannot take the command that fast through UART. Assuming I update duty to 0 in the first half and then 0.01s later, I set duty to something else (e.g., 50%). The module usually needs 200-300ms to process a command before I can send another one.
In another attempt, I use HW-517 (mosfet) module (like this). Pi's GPIO pin will control this mosfet module. This way, I try to power on/off the PWM module to stop it from generating waves. But it does not work as well. Although the module is on and off really quick, when I try to inspect it with a mini oscilloscope, it does not seem to be the correct wave (pic below).
In the experiment, I set frequency to 5Hz and duty to 50%. I tried to turn on and off 3 times, waiting 100ms in between. After I do that, I turn on for 5 seconds (just to test). But the wave looks 'frozen'. This makes me thing turning the module on and off may damage it or it's just wrong technically.

How should I achieve that intermittent pattern? Maybe it is not a good idea to use such module like XY-LPWM?
Thank you very much!
Edit: I ended up using a STM32 to generate the PWM waves.

Hello.  What is "PEMF" please?

PEMF Mat, Pulsed Electromagnetic Field Therapy ...

@jonathanjo Hi. Antonio is correct. It is pulsed electromagnetic field therapy. Simply put (in my own words), it is to use waves to control electricity through copper coils (1, 2 or many coils). The PWM waves I'm trying to produce above will be used as trig/pwm inputs to HW-517 modules. Then, these would connect to the coils.

What is your circuit? Post a schematic
